# Pass value of form input to a sibling component in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have created a form, and as the user makes their selections I would like to pass the value of the form input to a sibling component in real time.

I am using react-hook-form and am successfully able to use [watch](https://react-hook-form.com/api#watch) to see what values the user is entering, but I only know how to pass this to a child, not a sibling.

**App.js**

This is the parent

```
import React from 'react'
import Form from './Form';
import Message from './Message';

const App = () => {
  return (
     <div>
           <Form />
           <Message/>
     </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

**Form.js**

This is the child.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Select, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

function Form() {

const {control, watch } = useForm();    
const watchDiet = watch('diet');

return(
   <form>
          <label htmlFor="diet">Dietary requirements</label>
          <Controller
            as={
              <Select name="diet">
                  <MenuItem value="meat">Meat eater</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="veggie">Vegetarian</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="vegan">Vegan</MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            }
            control={control}
            name="diet"
            id="diet"
          />

    </form>
);
}
export default Form;
```

**Message.js**

This is a sibling of the child. I would like to pass the values into this component

```
import React from 'react';
const Message= (props) => {
  return (
      <div>
           If the user selects "Meat eater" in Form.js I want to 
           pass the value "meat" into this component
       </div>);
};
export default Message;
```

I'm quite new to React, so struggling to think how to do this. Wny guidance would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Katie

Comment: Where are you getting the ```control``` object from in Form.js?

Comment: sorry, am quite busy now. But I have few suggestions. You need to pass callback as props to Form and call that callback if certain condition is met. You need to have a method to handle that callback which would write that value to a state variable. Then pass that state variable to Message component as props.

Comment: @Adam Jeliński - That's a good point....it looks like I've tried to cut down my code too aggressively! I'll amend.

Comment: @awran5 - you're right. I missed that off too! I'll make another amend. In my real code this is in a child component but I've put it all into the form for ease of explanation (except it's not that easy if I leave things out!!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is put your `useForm()` hook inside the `App.js` so it's accessible for both of the children:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Form from './Form';
import Message from './Message';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const App = () => {
    const { watch, control } = useForm();    

    return (
        <div>
            <Form 
                watch={watch}
                control={control}
            />
            <Message
                watch={watch}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
export default App;
```

**Form.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const Form = ({ watch, control }) => {
    const watchDiet = watch('diet');

    return(
        <form>
            <label htmlFor="diet">Dietary requirements</label>
            <Controller
                as={
                    <Select name="diet">
                        <MenuItem value="meat">Meat eater</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value="veggie">Vegetarian</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value="vegan">Vegan</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                }
                control={control}
                name="diet"
                id="diet"
            />

        </form>
    );
}
export default Form;
```

Comment: I'm loving the idea of this. Thank you Adam! My code is a lot more complex than I have shown in my example, but I'm going to give it a go and will let you know if it works! :-)

Comment: Adam, you genius! I've reworked my code as you have suggested and it works perfectly. Thank you ever so much for your reply and for responding so quickly as well. Would give you more ticks if I could!!

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm very happy I could help :) This is based on the React guidelines about [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) if you would like to know more about how this problem can be solved.

Comment: Great, thanks for that reference - that's super useful!

Comment: this wasn't quite my usecase but still proved super valuable - very good!